# append div to specific place inside divs block with jquery

Tags: append

for sure its the easiest thing... 
i need to append a certain div to a specific place inside a div block and after a specific div.
this is my code:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
  <div class="ulWrap">
  <div class="apple-logo">
  <div class="android-logo">
  <div class="mmBtn"></div>
  <div class="mmBtnC"></div>
</div>
```

i need to insert a new div right after the:

```
<div class="logo">
```

i tried:

```
$('the div i want to append').eq(0).appendTo('.header');
```

but it appended it after the last div.

Comment: i tried:  $('***the div i want to append***').eq(0).appendTo('.header');
but i appended it after the last div.

Answer (score 0):

try `after()`:

```
$('.logo').after('<div>some new div</div>');
```

Comment: it places the div inside th "logo" div.
i need it after it.